# Regular expression for 3 decimal point in flutter

Tags: regex, flutter

I want to achieve the following:

3 digits before decimal point and a single digit after it
( while it also checks that starting 3 digits that are added should not have 0 as the first digit )

- Correct: 230.8,  179.0, 200.0 etc
- Incorrect: 012.4, 002.5, 12. , 12.22, 1.4, 1.222

for now i have this

```dart
  TextFormField(
    focusNode: participantHeightFocus,
    // inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
    inputFormatters: [
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
          RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d*$')),
    ],
    validator: (value) {
      if (value!.isEmpty) {
        return "Height is required";
      } else if (!RegExp(r'^\d+(\.\d+)').hasMatch(value)) {
        return "Please enter the height in cm (e.g., 170.0 cm)";
      }
      return null;
    },
    controller: participantHeight,
    onChanged: (_) => calculateBMIAndUpdate(),

    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Participant Height (*)",
      labelText: "Participant Height (*)",
      labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
    ),
  ),
```

it displays error but lets me enter many digits before decimal and many digits after decimal and it also allows me to start my number with 0 which is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
r'^[1-9]\d{2}\.\d$'
```

If you want the decimal point and digit to be optional (if e.g. 170.0 can also be written as 170), adjust it a little:

```
r'^[1-9]\d{2}(\.\d)?$'
```

Explanation:

- ^ matches the start of the string
- [1-9] matches every digit except 0
- \d{2} matches two digits
- \.\d matches the point and one digit
- $ matches the end of the string
- (...)? makes the expression inside the parantheses optional